# Modal dialog on Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I have a big enough problem with modal dialog. I noticed that in chrome when I use the modal dialog the parent page is not disabled while in IE is disabled. How do I solve this problem? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the asp.net ajax libraries. The modal popup available at: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx